# is it possible to show table something like this?

Tags: php, mysql

ok is it possible to show something like this

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","login");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
  ////////////////////////////////user1
  if($session->username=='user1')
{
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th><b>column1</b></th>
<th><b>column2</b></th>
<th><b>column3</th>
/tr>";

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM test WHERE user1 == 0 ");
//if($result =='0')
    //{
        //echo"Nothing to show";
    //}
//else

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  if ($row['user1'] == '1'){echo "<td> confirmed </td>";} elseif ($row['user1'] == '2') {echo "<td> not confirmed </td>";} else{echo "<td>waiting</td>";}
  if ($row['user2'] == '1'){echo "<td>confirmed </td>";} elseif ($row['user2'] == '2') {echo "<td> not confirmed </td>";} else{echo "<td>waiting</td>";}
  if ($row['user3'] == '1'){echo "<td> confirmed </td>";} elseif ($row['user3'] == '2') {echo "<td> not confirmed </td>";} else{echo "<td>waiting</td>";}
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
}
```

just help me on this
i got error 
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in

Comment: Change your question structure. Instead of asking *is it possible to show table something like this?* try to address the **real question** or bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in mysql the comparison operator is `=` and not, like in PHP, `==`.

So write:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM test WHERE user1 = 0 ");
// Only one `=` sign here ----------------------------------^
```

If you experience further problems of this type, have first a look at the value of `$con->error` after the execution of your query.

Comment: @user2490364 As this answer solved your problem, consider upvoting and accepting it, by clicking on the large green tick mark (✔) under the answer's score. (only possible after 15 minutes after asking your question)

Comment: yeah im waiting that 15 min

Comment: hey @bwoebi can i do something like this $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM test WHERE user3 = 0 and user2 <> 1"); seems its not working any suggest?

Comment: if user3 logged in it will show table only where user3=0 and user2= not 1

Comment: @Mooho058 `SELECT * FROM test WHERE user3 = 0 and user2 != 1` should work? (if the columns user2 and user3 exist)